# Statistics of usage of .NET Framework and Core

Tags: .net-core, compatibility, .net-framework-version

We're trying to select a minimum .NET Framework version for a new business software product. We're trying to balance compatibility with modern NuGet libraries against compatibility with business infrastructure. The product will run on .NET Core and .NET Framework.

For .NET Core targeting 3.1 is an easy decision, but for .NET Framework the choice is much less clear. We want to minimize the chances of users having to upgrade their .NET Framework version, as this is often difficult in a corporate environment, but if we choose to implement compatibility with really old version, such as .NET Framework 4.0, then we can't use a lot of modern NuGet packages.

One thing that could help us make this decision is statistics on which .NET Frameworks businesses have installed. Does anyone know where we can find such statistics?

Comment: I think it`s hard to find real true statistics you need. My advice, choose Net Core and make a standalone release and forget about the framework, if you still have not a lot of legacy code yet.

Comment: .net 4.8 is last classic .net framework version. so pick this version as it is already included in lastest Windows 10 versions (1903, 1909, 2004)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Along with .NET Core 3.1, we've decided to target .NET Framework 4.6.1 as this is supported by Windows Server 2016 and also allows us to use libraries that target .NET Standard 2.0.